# Can i call tableView cellForRowAtIndexPathtableView in heightForRowAtIndexPath to find cell's size if I have a custom cell?

Tags: uitableview, height, cell, xib

Can I call `tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPathtableView` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to find cell's size?

Is it too expensive in terms of performance, if not how else can I find cells height if it comes from XIB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. It won't work anyway. `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for all of your cells. And `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` won't return cells for the non visible indexPaths anyway.

When `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called the first time (just after `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`) there is no cell at all.

Just check the height of the cell in interface builder. Select the UITableViewCell view and look into the size panel.

[image]

Because `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every cell you should set the height of the cells in viewDidLoad if you only have one height. If `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is not implemented it is not called, which is great if you have many cells.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 44.0f;
}
```

If you have different heights, figure out the height from your dataSource. E.g. check the object at the indexPath from your dataSource NSArray and use the same logic you use in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to figure out which cell to use. Then return the appropriate height.

---

EDIT: I just tested it and querying the tableView for a cell in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static CGFloat cellHeight = 0;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifyer"];
        cellHeight = cell.height;
    });

return cellHeight;
}
```